# Potentially failed drive visible in udisksctl, but not other tools

Tags: hard-drive

One of my Seagate drives stopped responding and after I logged in to the system remotely I was displayed a number of errors related to this drive (buffer I/O error, access beyond end of device), more information
[here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vojk.jpg)

I try to troubleshoot the issue (or at least to understand whether is there any chance to reanimate the drive), but all guides which I have found assume that disk is seen by lsblk, df and other tools like fsck, badblocks etc. Unfortunately this is not the case, the only command which points to any information about the mentioned sdak drive is udisksctl:

```
sudo udisksctl info -b /dev/sdak

/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdak:
  org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block:
    Configuration:              []
    CryptoBackingDevice:        '/'
    Device:                     /dev/sdak
    DeviceNumber:               16960
    Drive:                      '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/ST18000NM000J_2T_<serial>'
    HintAuto:                   false
    HintIconName:               
    HintIgnore:                 false
    HintName:                   
    HintPartitionable:          true
    HintSymbolicIconName:       
    HintSystem:                 true
    Id:                         by-id-ata-ST18000NM000J-<serial>
    IdLabel:                    
    IdType:                     
    IdUUID:                     
    IdUsage:                    
    IdVersion:                  
    MDRaid:                     '/'
    MDRaidMember:               '/'
    PreferredDevice:            /dev/sdak
    ReadOnly:                   false
    Size:                       0
    Symlinks:                   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST18000NM000J-<serial>
                                /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0ATA_ST18000NM000J-2T_<serial>
                                /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-1ATA_ST18000NM000J-<serial>
                                /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500c87181f8
                                /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_ST18000NM000J-2T_<serial>
                                /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500c87181f8
                                /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:0d:00.0-ata-3
```

Any recommendations for potential next steps?

Comment: Hello. Try and back up any data you need and replace the drive.

Comment: @David unfortunately I cannot even mount the drive

Comment: I did say TRY. How old is the drive just as a point of interest.